# Is pyramid link building a good practice for SEO?

Tags: seo, backlinks, link-building

Can someone help me to understand please?

Is pyramid link building a to do practice for SEO?
Does it work as per example below?

Tier 3 pyramid building for SEO...

- Tier 3 site, links to Tier 2 site...
- Tier 2 site has *keyword* links to profile site
- Profile site has links to `http://yourdomain.com/`

Does Google associate the *keyword* with your domain, thus ranking it higher within the search field?

Comment: Honestly, does that seem like a normal practice to you? What benefit do users get from what you described?

Answer (score 10):

Any type of Pyramid link building scheme is considered black hat and punishable by Google's Link Spam Updates AKA - [Google Penguin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Penguin).

The idea of using a 2 and 3 tier system was that you could spam some low quality links to the tier 3 and then dribble it down to the 2nd and then to the main site (Money Site) and the money site would not be punished since they would only have a couple of incoming links with the weight of 10,000s and 100,000's being dripped from Tier 2 and 3 sites.

Google isn't stupid and is forever improving their engine to detect such schemes and the simple Pyramid T2 and T3 system has been detectable for some time. We now have people using 10 tiers upwards but this again leaves a footprint and Google has said this year we can [expect the biggest Penguin update](http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-on-upcoming-penguin-panda-link-networks-updates-151273) which is going to shake the world and black hatters upside down.

**Build great content**

Rather than spending time on systems that are likely to get you punished at a later date as MILLIONS have already and its worth noting that less than 1% come back after being hit by penguin. You are better of creating good content and getting back links the natural way for a long term strat... Black hat today is now considered a Quick Win, then lose.

Comment: That's great feedback and certainly what I feared.

The sad thing is the company I am working with has already purchased this service from a SEO Company and the damage may have been done now.

Any advise moving forward?

Comment: My advice would be focus on 'Bait Link' pages that really inspire people to link to you on, the biggest problem with Google manipulation is that at some point they 'may' catch you, Some schemes are do work but the money involved, the time involved its more constructive as a long-term viable option to do things that Google loves. In regards of Bait Links things like say for example you have a page about Cats you run a competition for the best pictures submitted and someone wins a cat collar or something like that, they even give you content to add to your site so its a win win.

Comment: As well as giving social indications to Google as well as many people will like the page, I strongly believe in this day and age Google uses Social Likes/Tweets to measure trust of a site, many spam type sites in Tiers for example have 0 likes with 10,000 back links - this is very detectable and how likely is it to naturally gain 10,000 links with no likes? it just doesn't happen. Also videos on YouTube is a great way of gaining trust from Google as well as Direct traffic from YouTube as well as if your embedding videos on the page then this lowers the bounce rate and increases time visited.

Comment: Thanks heaps bybe, your knowledge and advice is well received and very appreciated.

Comment: One of our competitors found the rewards of Black Hat SEO to be "Six Months to Bankruptcy" once Google pronounced the death penalty. If you looked exactly for their business name, you could get one single page to show in the SERPs. Basically, consider the company to be a resume stain.